# Eliminate Bing as Lock Screen app

Tags: windows, lock-screen, bing

I see options for changing the Lock Screen to a picture or a slide show in the "Personalize" popup; what I'd really like to be able to do is see the pretty pictures but not have them use Bing & Edge to display information about them when they're clicked on. I don't do that any more myself, but my wife would like to and doesn't understand why it doesn't use her default browser.

I suspect MS has locked this in on purpose so that pretty-picture-lovers will always get Bing and Edge, in their vain hope that someone will start to prefer them over any other search engine/browser.

But I thought I'd ask -- any way to get it to quit using Bing/Edge?

Comment: Don’t use Edge. You cannot uninstall it. Install your own browser and make it default. Use a plain theme and a picture only for your Lock Screen. Working here on several Windows 10 and up machines including VMs